# Can we give a custom metric for cross-validation with GLM in H2O?

Tags: python, r, h2o

I am trying to use `h2o.glm` to find the optimal penalty `lambda` by cross-validation. This is a multinomial model.

However, I see that it is optimizing according to the multinomial deviance. Can I do cross-validation with respect to some other metric, such as misclassification error?

The parameter `custom_metric_func` is mentioned in the docs, but I am not clear on its description. Is this metric used as the cross-validation score? If yes, the docs also state that it is only available in the `Python` API. Is this really true?

Answer (score 2):

If you are definitively working on h2o, then the suitable option to not leave the R interface with h2o would be to use the options `keep_cross_validation_models = TRUE, keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,`. from  this you could build the misclassification error, of each category, on each model fitted with a specific sequence of values for lambda.  Alternatively, you could loop or lapply through a sequence of lambdas. for example `for (i in lambda_vector){ models[[i]]= h2o.glm(...,lambda= i )}`. Each one of the objects has a confusion matrix hence you could pontentially compute the classification error for each category. And you could make your own selection criterion.   The custom metric does work only in python.

if you can use just R:

to fit a multinomial model with an elastic penalty I would recommend , if there is not a particular reason to be tied to h2o,  to use the package [glmnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf) that provides the command  cv.glmnet() with the options family="multinomial" and type.measure="class". This would yield a multinomial model chosen by cross validation on the clasification error.

Comment: Those are helpful suggestions to work around the limitations of the R API. However, I want to confirm: Are you saying that with the Python API,  `custom_metric_func` will work how I want for cross-validation? It wasn't clear in the documentation what exactly this option does.

Yes, I need to use R because of its document generating abilities. Another possible workaround is to call the Python API from R using `reticulate`. 

Yes, I have already used `glmnet`, but H2O has additional statistics for feature importance that `glmnet` is lacking and I'm not sure what their formula is.

Comment: Disclaimer  I have not tried this in R. You write a custom metric: `mymetric` in a  script.py   and upload it to the cluster as in [this link](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/dev/custom_functions.md)  then specify the option `custom_metric_function=mymetric`. This definitively works with [python](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-xu/6/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/custom_metric_func.html). You could test it in R. Since the function is in the cluster I guess you should be able to access it in R. But is just a guess.

Comment: I could not understand the custom metric code in the link you provided. For example, their descriptions of `map`, `reduce` and `metric` were not clear at all. So I implemented my own lambda loop similar to what you described, but using `h2o.grid` to do a grid search on labmda. I will post this in a separate answer.

Comment: Great I am glad you figured it out

Comment: Thanks, but it would probably have been better to figure out how to use their `custom_metric_func`.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `h2o.glm_custom` as a "replacement" for `h2o.glm` that keeps the cross validation models, so that a custom selection criterion can be used afterwords, as suggested by @Diegolog. My approach uses `h2o.grid`. I attempted to include all of the parameters for `h2o.glm` but simplified some defaults to avoid extra work.

```
h2o.glm_custom <- function(x,
                           y,
                           training_frame,
                           model_id = NULL,
                           validation_frame = NULL,
                           nfolds = 0,
                           seed = -1,
                           keep_cross_validation_models = TRUE,
                           keep_cross_validation_predictions = FALSE,
                           keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment = FALSE,
                           fold_assignment = "AUTO",
                           fold_column = NULL,
                           random_columns = NULL,
                           ignore_const_cols = TRUE,
                           score_each_iteration = FALSE,
                           offset_column = NULL,
                           weights_column = NULL,
                           family = "binomial",
                           rand_family = c("[gaussian]"),
                           tweedie_variance_power = 0,
                           tweedie_link_power = 1,
                           theta = 1e-10,
                           solver = "AUTO",
                           alpha = 0,
                           early_stopping = TRUE,
                           nlambdas = 100,
                           standardize = TRUE,
                           missing_values_handling = "MeanImputation",
                           plug_values = NULL,
                           compute_p_values = FALSE,
                           remove_collinear_columns = FALSE,
                           intercept = TRUE,
                           non_negative = FALSE,
                           max_iterations = -1,
                           objective_epsilon = -1,
                           beta_epsilon = 1e-04,
                           gradient_epsilon = -1,
                           link = "family_default",
                           rand_link = "[identity]",
                           startval = NULL,
                           calc_like = FALSE,
                           HGLM = FALSE,
                           prior = -1,
                           lambda_min_ratio = 0.01,
                           beta_constraints = NULL,
                           max_active_predictors = -1,
                           obj_reg = -1,
                           export_checkpoints_dir = NULL,
                           balance_classes = FALSE,
                           class_sampling_factors = NULL,
                           max_after_balance_size = 5,
                           max_hit_ratio_k = 0,
                           max_runtime_secs = 0,
                           custom_metric_func = NULL) {

  # Find lambda_max
  model <- h2o.glm(x,
                   y,
                   training_frame,
                   model_id,
                   validation_frame,
                   nfolds,
                   seed,
                   keep_cross_validation_models,
                   keep_cross_validation_predictions,
                   keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment,
                   fold_assignment,
                   fold_column,
                   random_columns,
                   ignore_const_cols,
                   score_each_iteration,
                   offset_column,
                   weights_column,
                   family,
                   rand_family,
                   tweedie_variance_power,
                   tweedie_link_power,
                   theta,
                   solver,
                   alpha,
                   NULL, # lambda
                   TRUE, # lambda_search
                   early_stopping,
                   1, # nlambdas
                   standardize,
                   missing_values_handling,
                   plug_values,
                   compute_p_values,
                   remove_collinear_columns,
                   intercept,
                   non_negative,
                   max_iterations,
                   objective_epsilon,
                   beta_epsilon,
                   gradient_epsilon,
                   link,
                   rand_link,
                   startval,
                   calc_like,
                   HGLM,
                   prior,
                   lambda_min_ratio,
                   beta_constraints,
                   max_active_predictors,
                   obj_reg = obj_reg,
                   export_checkpoints_dir = export_checkpoints_dir,
                   balance_classes = balance_classes,
                   class_sampling_factor = class_sampling_factors,
                   max_after_balance_size = max_after_balance_size,
                   max_hit_ratio_k = max_hit_ratio_k,
                   max_runtime_secs = max_runtime_secs,
                   custom_metric_func = custom_metric_func)

  lambda_max <- model@model$lambda_best

  # Perform grid search on lambda, with logarithmic scale
  lambda_min <- lambda_max * lambda_min_ratio
  grid <- exp(seq(log(lambda_max), log(lambda_min), length.out = nlambdas))
  grid_list <- lapply(sapply(grid, list), list)
  hyper_parameters <- list(lambda = grid_list)

  result <- h2o.grid('glm',
                     x = x,
                     y = y,
                     training_frame = training_frame,
                     nfolds = nfolds,
                     family = family,
                     alpha = alpha,
                     ignore_const_cols = ignore_const_cols,
                     hyper_params = hyper_parameters,
                     seed = seed)
}
```

Then the following function could be used to select lambda based on misclassification error:

```
get_cv_means <- function(grid_results) {
  mean_errors <- lapply(grid_results@model_ids, function(id) {
    model <- h2o.getModel(id)
    lambda <- model@parameters$lambda
    err <- as.numeric(model@model$cross_validation_metrics_summary['err', 'mean'])
    data.frame(lambda = lambda, error = err)
  })
  dt <- data.table::rbindlist(mean_errors)
  data.table::setkey(dt, lambda)
  dt
}
```

Here is a complete example using these function to select lambda using cross validation based on misclassification error:

```
h2o.init()
path <- system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package= "h2o")
h2o_df <- h2o.importFile(path)
h2o_df$CAPSULE <- as.factor(h2o_df$CAPSULE)
lambda_min_ratio <- 0.000001
nlambdas <- 100
nfolds <- 20

result <- h2o.glm_custom(x = c("AGE", "RACE", "PSA", "GLEASON"),
                         y = "CAPSULE",
                         training_frame = h2o_df,
                         family = "binomial",
                         alpha = 1,
                         nfolds = nfolds,
                         lambda_min_ratio = lambda_min_ratio,
                         nlambdas = nlambdas,
                         early_stopping = TRUE)

tbl <- get_cv_means(result)
```

Gives:

```
> head(tbl)
lambda     error
1: 2.222376e-07 0.2264758
2: 2.555193e-07 0.2394541
3: 2.937851e-07 0.2380508
4: 3.377814e-07 0.2595451
5: 3.883666e-07 0.2478443
6: 4.465272e-07 0.2595603
```

Which can be plotted, etc...

```
  ggplot() + geom_line(data = tbl[lambda < 0.00001], aes(x = lambda, y = error))
```

[image: CV misclassificaiton error]